# How to access to the TermStore and Managed Metadata Service from SharePoint FrameWork WebPart (React/SharePoint 2016)

Tags: sharepoint-server, managed-metadata

I would like to perform read operations on TermStore and Managed MetaData Service from my SPFX WebPart (React).

Is there any Rest API I can use ?
Can I use PnP JS ?
Or is there any other way to do it ?

Regards,

Arioule